# PROPAGATION_NESTED vs PROPAGATION_Required in spring?

Tags: spring, transactions

Actually looking for difference between PROPAGATION_NESTED( Execute within a nested transaction if a current transaction exists)  and PROPAGATION_Required(Support a current transaction).

Below is simple usecase

say in main class we call method1 and create the customer using jdbc[Transaction1]. Not commited yet.now we call the method2 in main class and create the account for the just created customer[Transaction2]. now commit it. can we call  transactions 2 as nested transaction.

As per my understanding now if we define the transaction definition as PROPAGATION_NESTED

transaction 2 will be treated as nested but if we define it as PROPAGATION_Required it will support the current transaction. so whats the differnce between nested and required?

Answer (score 8):

PROPAGATION_NESTED can only be used with a `DataSourceTransactionManager` and a JDBC3 driver. It uses save points in order to be able to rollback some part of a transaction (i.e. what constitutes the nested transaction in Spring terms). See the [javadoc of Connection](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/Connection.html) to see how save points work.

REQUIRED is completely different. It just means: if there is a transaction already existing, do the work in this transaction; else, start a new transaction, do the work, and commit the transaction.

Comment: Take a case of this example say in main class we call method1 and create the customer using jdbc[Transaction1]. Not commited yet.now we call the method2 in main class and create the account for the just created customer[Transaction2]. now commit it. As per your explanation both these transaction will be treated as part of one transaction(as there can be max one transaction with a connection)but if we use savepoints  to partially rollback or commit we call transactions 2 as nested transaction.Is this correct?

Answer (score 1):

Because you are using Spring with required/nested propagation, your [Transaction1] and [Transaction2] mentioned in the question are "The Same Transcation".

As your Use Case, if you use "required" on method2()

```
@Transaction(Require)
main() {
    // throw new Exception(); => rollback all
    method1();
    method2();
    // throw new Exception(); => rollback all
}

@Transaction(Require)
method1() {
    // throw new Exception(); => rollback all
}

@Transaction(Require)
method2() {
    // throw new Exception(); => rollback all
}
```

---

If you use nested on method2()

```
@Transaction(Require)
main() {
    // throw new Exception(); => rollback all
    method1();

    // Create Save Point A
    method2();
    // Release Save Point A

    // throw new Exception(); => rollback all
}

@Transaction(Require)
method1() {
    // throw new Exception(); => rollback all
}

@Transaction(Nested) // is the same transaction as main
method2() {
    // throw new Exception(); => will only rollback to Save Point A
}
```

---

Nested Transaction's Use Case

(when one customer need one million account, and it need couple of hour to complete all the task)

Benefit =>

1. One account create failure won't rollback all (only rollback the failure account => you can then start debug) [save time when company have midnight batch that deal with lots of independent data]
2. They are all in the same connection/transaction [save resource compare to require new]

ex:

```
@Transaction(Require)
main() {
    // throw new Exception(); => rollback all
    method1();

    for(many time) {
        // Create Save Point
        method2();
        // Release Save Point
    }

    // throw new Exception(); => rollback all (Be careful, it will rollback all!!!)
}

@Transaction(Require)
method1() {
    // throw new Exception(); => rollback all
}

@Transaction(Nested) // is the same transaction as main
method2() {
    // throw new Exception(); => will only rollback to Save Point
}
```